# Json Format in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this this JSON.

```json
{
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 1000
    }, {
        "name": "Udang",
        "data": 300
    }, {
        "name": "Baranang",
        "data": 12000
    }, {
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 1500
    }, {
        "name": "Udang",
        "data": 500
    }, {
        "name": "Baranang",
        "data": 17000
    }, {
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 2500
    }]
}
```

How can I group the `data` key by its name, to be like this:

```json
{
    "animals": [{
            "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
            "data": [
                1000, 1500, 2500
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "udang",
            "data": [
                300, 500
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Baranang",
            "data": [
                12000, 17000
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because I'm tired, but I can't figure out how to make this more concise...
This is a start for you anyway.

```php
$json = '{
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 1000
    }, {
        "name": "Udang",
        "data": 300
    }, {
        "name": "Baranang",
        "data": 12000
    }, {
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 1500
    }, {
        "name": "Udang",
        "data": 500
    }, {
        "name": "Baranang",
        "data": 17000
    }, {
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 2500
    }]
}';

// Start by decoding the JSON (I assume it comes as a string, if not, then ignore this).
$collection = collect(json_decode($json, true))
// Now iterate over the keys (you only have one key (animals), but I wanted to be safe).
->map(function ($item) {
    // Convert the sub arrays into a Collection, then group the data against each animal name.
    // Then map (iterate) over each of the animals, one at a time.
    return collect($item)->groupBy('name')->map(function ($animal) {
        // Reduce each animal into a single entry.
        return $animal->reduce(function ($carry, $data) {
            // Use the name of the animal, then push the data onto the end. Feel free to sort at this point too!
            $carry['name'] = $data['name'];
            $carry['data'][] = $data['data'];
            return $carry;
        });
    // Finally, I reset the groupBy keys to ensure it matches your desired output.
    })->values();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JustCarty's solution is probably better, but I wanted to post mine anyways.

```php
// get json string
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 1000
    }, {
        "name": "Udang",
        "data": 300
    }, {
        "name": "Baranang",
        "data": 12000
    }, {
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 1500
    }, {
        "name": "Udang",
        "data": 500
    }, {
        "name": "Baranang",
        "data": 17000
    }, {
        "name": "Cumi-Cumi",
        "data": 2500
    }]
}
JSON;
```

```php
$result = collect(json_decode($json, true)) // transform $json into a collection
    ->map(function ($item) { // map over it
        return collect($item); // make the animals array a collection
    })
    ->map(function ($animals) { // map over it
        return $animals
            ->unique('name') // leave only uniquely named animals
            ->map(function ($item) use ($animals) { // map over them
                return [
                    'name' => $item['name'],
                    'data' => $animals->where('name', $item['name'])->pluck('data')->all()
                ]; // replace their 'data' values by the array of 'data' from each unique animal.
            });
    })
    ->toJson(); // turn back to json string
```

Using PHP 7.4 shorthand closures:

```php
$results = collect(json_decode($json, true))
    ->map(fn($item) => collect($item))
    ->map(fn($item) => $item->unique('name')->map(fn($animal) => [
        'name' => $animal['name'],
        'data' => $item->where('name', $animal['name'])->pluck('data')->all()
    ]))
    ->toJson();
```